# Keep Pokémon Go from taking over audio

Tags: audio, pokemon-go

I like to drop into Pokémon Go while I'm out and about in the world. Trouble is that I'm usually listening to a podcast or some music, and as soon as I launch the app it takes over the audio, so that whatever I was listening to stops.

Of course, I have the settings for the app with music and sound effects off.

Is there a way to use the app while still listening to a podcast?

Comment: You could try using automation app like Macrodroid. Trigger would be Pokemon app launched, action would be muting various options (can't say which one for sure since i dont play Pokemon). Constraints would be your podcast app running

Comment: @beeshyams As I mentioned, I already have all of the sounds off in the Pokémon app. What would your suggestion accomplish?

Comment: I had seen that but suggested as I am not sure how the Pokemon app sends its sounds- *media/music, notification* are possibilities and can be muted - you would of course need to experiment. App is not available in India to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

When you listen to your podcast or music and launch Pokemon Go, the music stops playing. Go to your recent tasks, open your music/podcast app and start playing your music again. After that just open recent tasks again and switch over to pokemon go.

If your phone holds more than 1 app in RAM and is not killing them, this should work.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, for me at least, when I do that the Pokémon Go app restarts each time. If I had to guess I would say that I don't have enough RAM to keep both apps in memory.

Comment: Dunno if it's the latest version of the app or I was just persistent enough, but this just worked for me.

Comment: ... But if the app ever re-starts, it takes over the audio again. Until Niantic fixes things, though, this is as good as it gets.

Comment: ...although, to be fair, it could simply be that my device doesn't have enough RAM to hold both apps in memory and so is "killing" the one that's not in the forefront.

Answer (score 1):

I use Podcast Addict. If you go to their Settings then Player there is a checkbox under Experimental for "Ignore Audio Focus requests" this will allow the podcasts to play while playing Pokemon Go or most other apps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'm not inclined to change my podcatcher. This might be useful for someone else, though.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain  I'm looking for the same thing

But I found a work around similar to above but doesn't require you to "leave" Pokemon go

Just swipe down from the top and click play again 
If your music controls show up in the bag menu)l that is.
If it's not then add the music to the drop down using the Personalize options in the options

Of course it all depends on you phone + os version, but thats my least invasive workaround until I find another way

Comment: Thing is, they don't. For this particular scenario, Android was dumping the podcast app out of memory altogether. With other apps I'm able to do what you describe. Fortunately, Santa is bringing me a new phone with a lot more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I use an audio player that even loses its notification when I switch to Pokemon Go.

I found that a headset button press (wired or Bluetooth) will start my audio back up. The app I use does not get focus when this happens so I am still in Pokemon Go listening to my music.

Answer (score 0):

i found by when in game swiping up from bottom of screen and selecting the nintendo icon in the bottom left screen; i had "mute media" on.  by turning it off it allowed me to keep audio playing while using Pokemon Go